# Handle window.keyPress event in Aurelia app

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am wondering if anyone can provide any insight into how I would hook into the `window.keyPress()` event in an Aurelia app.  I am looking to capture bar code scanner input and direct the scanned text into the appropriate input based on what the scanned value is.

I tried putting `window.addEventListener("keypress", HandleKeyInput, false)` in the `activate()` of my view model but this errors from the app-router with 
"HandleKeyInput is not defined" even though I have this function in my view model.

I am wondering what the correct approach for this scenario would be in regard to Aurelia.

Comment: @cbernsdof did you try google?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=f7837c986c38adeac5a58b8007c28b2a**

```js
export class App {
  activate() {
    window.addEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyInput, false);
  }

  deactivate() {
   window.removeEventListener('keypress', this.handleKeyInput);
  }

  handleKeyInput = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Some good reading:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Comment: Good answer. Technically, does this code supposed to be in a custom attribute?

Comment: How can I handle the key press event for a textbox?